# why does the 0x00 character make System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine not write a new line?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unicode

```
Dim hex = "41"
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To hex.Length - 2 Step 2
        text.Append(Chr(Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)))
    Next
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.ToString)
```

working perfectly.. System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine writes the output itself in a new line.

```
 Dim hex = "4100"
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To hex.Length - 2 Step 2
        text.Append(Chr(Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)))
    Next
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.ToString)
```

but yet this fails.. (the output isn't itself in a new line) what's the explanation for that?

From what I know, doesn't System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline does something which looks like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(input)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\n")
```

so regardless of my input it should always have a newline char even if there is a terminating 00 char in my input?

Comment: is 4100 string representing as hex value?

Comment: You've discovered that Windows was written in C.  A language that treats a binary zero as a string terminator.  The debugger has the same problem, try inspecting text.ToString().  Note the missing double quote at the end of the displayed string.

Comment: what do you mean by try inspecting text.ToString(), isn't that what i'm trying to do already?

Comment: @shobhonk yep an A character + 0x00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the details describing what is going on here:

The `string` class in .net is an array of `char` start by pointer to the first `char` in the array and ends by the special "terminal" char `\0`.

When you convert the `00` to byte you get `0`. but `0` is just equals the terminal char `\0`

```
byte b = (byte)`\0`;\\the value of b will be 0
```

So the `Console.Write` will ignore all characters after the first `\0`!. Not only the console will behive this way but also the control components. for instance `textBox.Text` if you apply a string to it that does have the `\0` character, it will not will not display any character after `\0` "including the `\0` itself".

**Edit:**

> From what I know, doesn't System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline does something which looks like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(input)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\n")
```

I guesses that the `Debug.WriteLine` are not implemented in this way or else we will not notice that behavior. maybe it does concatenate the string with new line like `input + "\n"`.

I can diagnosing the `Console.WriteLine` using `Resharper` program. the code is:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public virtual void WriteLine(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        int length = value.Length;
        int num2 = this.CoreNewLine.Length;
        char[] destination = new char[length + num2];
        value.CopyTo(0, destination, 0, length);
        switch (num2)
        {
            case 2:
                destination[length] = this.CoreNewLine[0];
                destination[length + 1] = this.CoreNewLine[1];
                break;

            case 1:
                destination[length] = this.CoreNewLine[0];
                break;

            default:
                Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(this.CoreNewLine, 0, destination, length * 2, num2 * 2);
                break;
        }
        this.Write(destination, 0, length + num2);
    }
}
```

So it is concatenate the string value with the new line. so it will cause the same effect.

Comment: from what I know, doesn't System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline do a.. (see my edited question here no space)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's not `Debug.WriteLine` itself - it's the Windows control that's receiving the output, which is treating U+0000 as "end of string".

Try adding a `TextWriterTraceListener` writing to a file to the `Debug` listener collection, then look at the file in a binary file viewer and I suspect you'll see every character you thought you were writing.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, and still display *NULL* characters perform a `.Replace("\0", @"\0")` on your string before printing it.